# Single page in Joomla have a different site logo than other pages

Tags: css, joomla, themes

I've not used joomla much before. I'm trying to just get one page of a site that uses a Joomla template to have a different logo than the rest of the site, or even hide it. I'm mostly a Wordpress developer, so just don't know how this can be done in Joomla.

Is there a way to assign a body class to one specific page in Joomla and have it hide the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit a menu item, you want to look under "Advanced Options" and then "Page Display Options". There is a box for "Page Class" which adds a class to the page, so a body class as you wanted.

You can then tweak your template to show different pieces in CSS based on this class.

---

If you want to drastically alter the page, you can also assign different templates to different pages through the template manager. This takes a little more work (since you have to install and set up another template).

This would be the preferred way to handle a lot of changes so you don't have to have lots of competing CSS based on page classes.

Comment: The page class will not automatically be assigned to the body, rather this has to be implemented in the template. Usually, edit the index.php, and set <body class="<?php echo $pageclass; ?>" >. Different ways to fill the pageclass-variable is discussed here: http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_Page_Class_Suffix_in_Template_Code. Jonas